# how do I implement a completely custom draggable control?

Tags: c#, .net, custom-controls

I work on an application that requires some fancy custom controls.  Inheriting from the .net Control class has caused various problems and is making things harder as time goes on.  I won't get into the specifics here, but I am creating my own light weight control architecture to avoid some of these problems.  Things art working nicely, but I need to add drag and drop functionality into my architecture.

All of the methods that I have come up with so far seem messy and error prone.  I am mimicking the .net Control class in many ways, and have used the .net reflector to great benefit, but I am having a problem figuring out how to make my drag events fire (DragDrop, DragEnter, DragLeave).

I just can't think of a clean way to fire off these events.  Does anyone have any ideas?

---

So far, the best that I have come up with is to implement the IDropTarget interface and *hope* that my events will fire.  They do not.

---

@tamberg: I read through that article and it is not really what I am looking for (thank you though).  My problem is that I do not know how to implement the event system.  For example, how do I know when a data object is being dragged over my custom control class?  How can I raise these events (DragOver, DragDrop, etc)?

All of the controls in the example inherit from System.Windows.Forms.Control, which is what I am trying to avoid.

Answer (score 2):

Just a guess:

Windows Forms, Custom Controls Part 1: Mastering DragDrop
(http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/LANDragDrop.aspx)

Regards,
tamberg